# Adding constant number to specific index interval in python list in vectorized way (without using numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, vectorization

So, say I have an `int` list:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Now say I want to add 10 to elements from index 5 to index 10 (inclusive) so that after the operation the `arr` becomes:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13]
```

What is the fasted (or reasonably fast) way to do this in python without using numpy? I am looking for possibly non-loop solution and rather something in the spirit of vectorization.

Comment: `list != array`

Comment: There are no vectorized ways without using a library like `numpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward way is fine:

```
>>> arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
>>> for i in range(5, 10 + 1):
...     arr[i] += 10
...
>>> arr
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am trying to avoid for-loop since in the actual project i need to do this many times. So, looking for vectorized solution

Comment: @hmi then you *need numpy*. There are no vectorized solutions in plain Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a simple for loop:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

for i in range(5, 11):
    arr[i] += 10

print arr
#outputs: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13]
```